# On an explicit model for $\mathbf Q$ with the negation of the axiom of induction

Tags: logic, model-theory, peano-axioms, nonstandard-models

I've been thinking for a while about non standard models of Robinson Arithmetic (here on out referred to as $\mathbf Q$), specifically ones in which induction ($\mathbf{AI}$) fails. This could happen in two ways: (1) $\mathbf Q$ is left as is without induction and non standard models are analysed on it, and (2) we add the negation of $\mathbf{AI}$ to $\mathbf Q$ (a system which I've quirkly named [*Hume Arithmetic*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/induction-problem/#HumeProb)) and search for a model on it.

On this post I'll mainly focus on the latter approach. $\neg \mathbf{AI}$ implies that there exists a formula with a free variable $P$ such that $P(0) \wedge \forall x (P(x) \rightarrow P(x'))$ is true but $\forall x P(x)$ does not hold. I've been thinking for a few months about this on and off but can't seem to find any model that could satisfy $\neg \mathbf{AI}$, much less a specific formula. I know one must exist because for $\mathbf{Q}$ and $\mathbf{PA}$ to be different systems then $\mathbf{AI}$ has to be contingent in $\mathbf{Q}$.

Any help with ways to find such a model? And I know this might sound silly, but if you're going to give an explicit answer on a model can you add a spoiler warning? I realise that with my current skills and understanding I can't solve this but I'd still love to give it a try for myself, even if it's with a little help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Great question!

In my opinion, the simplest nonstandard model of $Q$ consists of **polynomials** (in one variable). Specifically, let $\mathfrak{P}$ be the set consisting of all integer-coefficient polynomials in the variable $x$ with positive leading coefficient ... and also the zero polynomial. With successor, addition, and multiplication defined in the obvious way, $\mathfrak{P}$ forms a model of $Q$, and this is easy to check.

*(At this point it's also a good idea to check that a couple other obvious ideas **don't** work: e.g. the set of all polynomials with integer coefficients does not yield a model of $Q$.)*

This is a really pretty structure, and something it's not hard to care about. But I claim that induction breaks in it ... really really badly in fact! You said you didn't want spoilers, so I've hidden the full answer below, but here's a hint: think about **parity** *(even vs. odd)*.

> The key idea is that, while every natural number is either even or odd, it doesn't make a whole ton of sense to ask whether the polynomial "$x$" is even or odd. This motivates the following counterexample to induction in $\mathfrak{P}$: look at the property $EoO(a)$ = "Either for some $b$ we have $S(b+b)=a$, or for some $b$ we have $b+b=a$." It's easy to check that in $\mathfrak{P}$, $(i)$ not every element satisfies $EoO$, but $(ii)$ 0 does satisfy EoO and $(iii)$ if $a$ satisfies $EoO$ then $S(a)$ also satisfies $EoO$. So this does in fact constitute a failure of induction in $\mathfrak{P}$.

---

Incidentally, you've had a huge bit of luck here in your choice of $Q$ specifically.

There are lots of theories between $Q$ and PA, generally of the form [ordered semiring axioms] + [some fragment of the whole induction scheme]. For example, the theory I$\Sigma_1$ consists of the ordered semiring axioms together with the induction scheme for $\Sigma_1$ formulas. This is an attractive theory in a lot of contexts, and - like $Q$ - the gap between it and PA is measured by induction. But there is an important sense in which $Q$ is tame in a way that I$\Sigma_1$ isn't: namely, [Tennenbaum's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennenbaum%27s_theorem). The theory I$\Sigma_1$ has no "easily describable" nonstandard models, so while you could ask the same question about I$\Sigma_1$ you couldn't get quite as snappy an answer.

In general, Tennenbaum's theorem explains a conspicuous gap in the literature: **why, in all the discussion of incompleteness of PA, are there no analyses of specific interesting nonstandard models of PA?** The answer is that Tennenbaum largely rules out this possibility. This also helps motivate $Q$: Robinson found a theory which is weak enough to have lots of interesting, easily-describable, and very different models while also being strong enough to be subject to Godel's incompleteness theorem.

Comment: As an aside, Hajek/Pudlak's book [Metamathematics of first-order arithmetic](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235421926) is **the** source on weak theories of arithmetic.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I love to see around here! I'll definitely give it a try, thank you so much ^^